# Basemap quiver arrows not showing on plot

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib-basemap

I have a global dataset of directions which I am trying to show for a small section of the world using a quiver plot. The arrows aren't showing on the plot though - just dots at each data point. My code is shown below with the created figure. How can I get the arrows to show? [image: Quiver plot - no arrows]

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import datetime 
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cPickle as pickle 
import numpy as np

file_name = 'file.nc'
file2 = Dataset(file_name, mode='r')

lons2 = file2.variables['lon'][:]
lats2 = file2.variables['lat'][:]
times2 = file2.variables['time'][:]
wind_dir = file2.variables['wind_dir'][:]

#limits for the plot 
#longitudes
x1 = 5
x2 = 7
#latitudes
y1 = 41
y2 = 43.4

plt.figure()
map = Basemap(resolution='f',projection='merc',area_thresh = 0.1, llcrnrlat=y1,urcrnrlat=y2,llcrnrlon=x1,urcrnrlon=x2,lat_ts=(x1+x2)/2)
map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.5)
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
map.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')

x,y = map(lons2,lats2)
map.quiver(x,y,np.cos(np.deg2rad(wind_dir)),np.sin(np.deg2rad(wind_dir)),edgecolor='k', facecolor='white', linewidth=.5)
```

I have also created a quiver plot for just one point in the relevant area (see code below) and an arrow was plotted. I am confused as to why this is achieving the desired result when the code above is not. (see figure)
[image]

```
target_lat = 43
target_lon = 6.35
diff = 1000
for i in range(3264):
    for j in range(82):
        lat = lats2[i,j]
        lon = lons2[i,j]
        lat_d = target_lat - lat
        lon_d = target_lon - lon
        diff_n = np.sqrt(lat_d**2 + lon_d**2)
        if diff_n < diff:
            diff = diff_n
            time_ix = i
            space_ix = j

x_t, y_t = map(lons2[time_ix,space_ix],lats2[time_ix,space_ix])
map.quiver(x_t,y_t,np.cos(np.deg2rad(wind_dir[time_ix,space_ix])),np.sin(np.deg2rad(wind_dir[time_ix,space_ix])),edgecolor='k', facec`olor='white', linewidth=.5)

plt.show()
file2.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
scale=10
```

into the quiver function has solved my problem.